# Is there a way to use global jest mocks with Quasar?

Tags: unit-testing, vue-test-utils, quasar, ts-jest

I want to mock my i18n object globally.
I'm following a [guideline](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/mocking-global-objects.html#settings-default-mocks-using-config). I'm creating `jest.init.ts` file inside my `jest` folder. It contains following rules:

```
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils"

config.mocks["$t"] = () => ""
```

But my tests fail with the error:

```
TypeError: _vm.$t is not a function
```

I've also tried to import quasar implementation of vue-test utils ('@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest'), but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://testing.quasar.dev/packages/unit-jest/.   Here is a section for mocking i18n.

Comment: yeah, I'm following this doc as well. But it doesn't say anything about global mocks.